# Custom hash set in typed racket leads to contract violation with syntax objects

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I have a [custom set](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/sets.html?q=set#(form._((lib._racket%2Fset..rkt)._define-custom-set-types))) and I want to use it in typed racket.  I
require it using `require/typed` with the `#:opaque custom-set?`
instruction.  It works, except that the code fails at run time when I
call `custom-set?` with a syntax object.

I have something like the following:

```lisp
#lang typed/racket/base

(module UNTYPED racket/base
  (require racket/set)
  (provide custom-set?
           make-immutable-custom-set)

  (define-custom-set-types custom-set
    #:elem? identifier?
    (λ (id1 id2) (eq? (syntax-e id1) (syntax-e id2)))))

(require/typed 'UNTYPED
  [#:opaque MySet custom-set?]
  [make-immutable-custom-set ((Listof Identifier) -> MySet)])

(custom-set? (make-immutable-custom-set (list #'foo #'bar)))  ;; #t
(custom-set? '())  ;; #f
```

Which type checks and returns `#t` or `#f` as expected.

Now, if I try to call the same `custom-set?` predicate with a syntax object:

```
(custom-set? #'(foo bar))
```

Then, I get the following contract violation instead of `#f`:

```
custom-set?: broke its own contract
  Attempted to use a higher-order value passed as `Any` in untyped code: #<syntax:stdin:: a>
  in: the 1st argument of
      a part of the or/c of
      (or/c
       struct-predicate-procedure?/c
       (-> Any boolean?))
  contract from: (interface for custom-set?)
  blaming: (interface for custom-set?)
```

The same call into the `UNTYPED` module works and returns `#f` as expected. Could you tell me why a syntax object breaks the contract here? And can I fix this?

Comment: Note: the same problem can happen with non-transparent structs `(struct x ()) (custom-set? (x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug caused by syntax-object contracts not being good enough. Specifically, the `syntax/c` contract works on flat contracts, while Typed Racket wants to work with chaperone contracts when the `Any` type is involved.

The `Any` that's involved here is the implicit `Any` introduced by `#:opaque` requiring the predicate `custom-set?`. It appears in an input, protecting values that start in typed code and end up in untyped code. Since untyped code could try to mess with a typed higher-order value, it must be wrapped with a chaperone contract `any-wrap/c` (internal to Typed Racket).

The `any-wrap/c` is there to protect potentially higher-order values, and container values that could contain higher-order values. If some part was mutable, or if some part had a function in it, untyped code cannot be allowed to mutate that data or call that function.

Syntax objects are containers. They can contain arbitrary values in the "syntax-e" and the syntax properties. Ideally, Typed Racket's `any-wrap/c` contract should wrap syntax objects in chaperone contracts that protect these places. Unfortunately, the `syntax/c` contract in the contract system isn't good enough for that. Because of this syntax objects are considered "unsafe" containers, and if `any-wrap/c` can't wrap them safely it must raise a contract error.

The only way I can see this potentially being fixed in the future is by improving `syntax/c` to work with chaperone contracts. After that `any-wrap/c` could consider syntax objects safe containers just like lists.